# using case statement to select all

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using the HR sample database here from Oracle. I want to have all values selected by using the literal string 'all' how would I go about doing that in SQL as default? I want to use this so typing the word all on a stored procedure will bring all Job_id.

Please see below an example.

```
select * from ##employees
where job_id in  (case when job_id = 'IT_PROG' then  'IT_PROG' else 'all'  end)
```

Comment: Ur statement is correct, should work.

Comment: Is it SQL Server or Oracle, you tagged both.

Answer (score 3):

```
select * from ##employees
where @var = 'all'
or job_id = @var
```